# How to print a object's value while debugging python in vscode?

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code

What function (if any) should I implement so that VScode (or really python) can pick up the value of a user defined object in the VScode variable pane whilst debugging?

In this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E9uUO.png) you can see that arr shows up as `[1, 2, 3, 4]`. How can I get the variable `node` to show its value (`1`) instead of `<__main__.ListNode object at 0x7f4a19eafb20>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `node` is an object, its corresponding `__repr__` method is returning that value by default. If you want to see the actual node `value` instead, then you can add a `__repr__` method to `ListNode` class.

VScode uses the `__repr__` method when showing the variable values. Here's a sample `ListNode` class with `__repr__` method added -

```
class ListNode(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.val = x
        self.next = None

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.val)


node = ListNode(1)
print(node)
```

If you run this in VScode debug mode you would see the expected node value instead of `<__main__.ListNode object at 0x101bed2b0>`

**Without `__repr__` method -**
[image]

**With `__repr__` method -**
[image]

Comment: what to do if I want to walk the List through the `next` pointer/handle in the debugger pane

Comment: @rioV8, you can still do that same as before, by expanding the tree under the node. You would see `next` object under `node` which would show node linked to `next` of current `node` object.

Comment: I tried and you are right, the `__repr__` only modifies the collapsed-text/object-title shown in the debugger, it has no influence on the traversal of objects